# Liferay : Timestamp Behaviour

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay

Is it possible to have a Timestamp behaviour in order to keep a record on the changes done on some entities in Liferay 6.1.1?

For example can Liferay add the colums : created_at, deleted_at on those entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *Can* you add entities to Liferay with these columns? *Yes*
- *Can* you add these columns to Liferay's own entities? *Yes*
- *Should* you add arbitrary columns to Liferay's entities while expecting a well behaving updateable system? *No*

When a record is deleted, what row do you expect a *deleted_at* column to be on? Liferay 6.2 has a Recycle Bin which will keep the deletion date for the entities that it covers. Other entities (and those in 6.1) will be deleted from the database when they're deleted.

And yes, you can override all services of Liferay with your own implementation - for example one that keeps track of those changes and saves the required information in a separate table or database.